# Why Does My Windows Form Visual Look Like This?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to figure out what's the reasoning for the visual change when I build and run the application but in the visual studio, it displays the normal visual. I've been experiencing this issue for a minute now, & can't find any solution nor the cause. I think It started when I published the application but clearly that is not how I want to display the application to other users. I already know this is probably a very simple solution to this issue but I'm learning. Can someone explain?

It's A .Net 5 Application, I Recently Just Transferred From .Net Framework.

Comment: Application.EnableVisualStyles() is missing.  How you did that is not obvious, it is normally enabled with Project > Properties > Application tab > "Enable XP visual styles" checkbox.

Comment: I've been experiencing which seems to be a flaw/bug with visual studio with multiple projects, some occasions when I change the form like simply just move a textbox control, it will reset the .designer file (I'm using custom controls previously I changed the namespace for it and when I modify the form it would reset it back to an old namespace) and in this case, it constantly keeps resetting the Application.Designer.vb From Me.MainForm = Global.Remote_Desktop_Program.RdpForm To Me.MainForm = Global.Remote_Desktop_Program.Form1 randomly.

Comment: It tells you right at the top of the file: "Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if the code is regenerated."  Do **not** edit the designer.vb files.

Comment: I get an error "Form1" is not a member of 'Remote_Desktop_Program', but in the projects settings, the startup object is "Rdpform" and I also tried "Sub Main" that's why I modified the file directly to "Rdpform" due to that error.

Comment: Not disclosing any of this in your question is quite unwise.   https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when the default `Main` method was modified and the call to [`Application.EnableVisualStyles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.enablevisualstyles?view=net-5.0) was removed.

Without this call, controls will be drawn in the default "flat" style regardless of the system's visual style setting.

Comment: I've been experiencing which seems to be a flaw/bug with visual studio with multiple projects, some occasions when I change the form like simply just move a textbox control, it will reset the .designer file (I'm using custom controls previously I changed the namespace for it and when I modify the form it would reset it back to an old namespace) and in this case, it constantly keeps resetting the Application.Designer.vb From Me.MainForm = Global.Remote_Desktop_Program.RdpForm To Me.MainForm = Global.Remote_Desktop_Program.Form1 randomly cause I have Enable XP Visual Styles on in settings.